# Why isn't deque implemented as a dynamic array?

Tags: algorithms, queues, c++

We know that `std::vector` in C++ is implemented as a dynamic array with specific pattern of reallocation (multiplying capacity by a constant), which allows it to reach O(1) amortized `push_back` time. But changing capacity of a vector is essentially allocation of new memory block and copying old data into it. That means we can as well implement a vector which can grow in both directions with amorized O(1) `push_back` and `push_front` time.

But `std::deque` is implemented in different, rather complicated way, not storing data in a contiguous manner and suffering from related issues (e.g. more frequent page faults when iterating). Why so? Are there any obstacles disallowing to implement deque as a dynamic array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `std::deque` is implemented as a sequence of non-contiguous blocks is to guarantee different complexity bounds (and different concrete performance) for operations with regards to `std::vector`.

You already partially said it: changing the capacity of an `std::vector` requires reallocating the memory and copying the *entire* content to the new memory. While it is true that the `std::vector`reallocation scheme achieves a O(1) amortised complexity, the implementation of `std::deque` guarantees a true O(1) complexity bound for appending.

Comment: Oh. Apparently resource I was reading mistakenly stated it's amortised O(1)... Thank you for clarifying!